# Short story about consumers vs producers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to remember the title of a short story I read back in the 90s. The parents were producers who produced all the goods included weapons and ammunition. The children were consumers who used the weapons and ammunition in a continual battle at night.

Answer (score 6):

["Consumer's Report" aka "No Gun to the Victor"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71475) by Theodore R. Cogswell.

> CON.SUM.ER (KON-SUM-ER), *n*., 1. *a person who destroys, uses up, or wastes industrial production in order to control the size of the population and make possible the full employment that is necessary for a healthy economy.* 2. *one who has not yet achieved producer status.* 3. *Any person under twenty-one.* 4. (*Obs*.) *A person who uses goods or services to satisfy his needs rather than to resell them or to produce other goods with them.*
> —*The Authorized Dictionary* (*New Washington, Kansas. The Federal Printing Office, 3rd ed.,* 1944)